# Gtk "subtle" Progress Bar

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am wondering how to achieve a progressbar / loader indicator similiar to the one Epiphany (aka Gnome Web) is using. See the provided screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading the Epiphany source code right, it's just a styled `GtkProgressBar`:

https://github.com/GNOME/epiphany/blob/9b9be55de3cd74a0f0cb05880177db7b46d10923/embed/ephy-embed.c#L727

```
priv->progress = gtk_progress_bar_new ();
gtk_style_context_add_class (gtk_widget_get_style_context (priv->progress),
                             GTK_STYLE_CLASS_OSD);
```

The `GTK_STYLE_CLASS_OSD` style class is described [like this in the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-OSD:CAPS):

> **GTK_STYLE_CLASS_OSD**
>
> `#define GTK_STYLE_CLASS_OSD "osd"`
>
> A CSS class used when rendering an OSD (On Screen Display) element, on top of another container.